# How to set proportional width based on parent container with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a div which has a dynamic width (using percentage size). Inside this I have two buttons, and here comes the issue, I have to make this two buttons have the same length of the container.

So far I have succeeded in make the first button have a dynamic width, but this 2 buttons do not cover all the with of the container

here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/1273/)

you can see in the fiddle, css class: "btn-stretch", this class takes 85% of the parent container

so those two buttons need to be the same width as the input field.

this is the basic structure:

```
<div>
   <input widthDynamic1/>
</div>
<div>
   <button1 widthDynamic2/>
   <button2 widthStatic3/>
</div>
```

where:

```
widthDynamic1 = widthDynamic2 + widthStatic3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this css properties:

```
.btn-group {width:100%;}
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {

    width: calc(100% - 26px);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/1275/)**